# How to integrate $\sinh(x)$ as Riemann sum

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I have a task where I need to calculate $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \sinh(x) \,dx$. I know that to integrate $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(x) \,dx$ we take $\Delta x_i = \dfrac{\pi }{ 2n}$ and $x_i =  \dfrac{i\pi }{2n}$, so

$\displaystyle \epsilon_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin\left(\frac{i\pi}{2n}\right) \times \frac{\pi}{2n}$ where we can use that $\dfrac {\sin(x)}{x}$ is very close to 1 when $x$ is close to 0 to simplify.

But what to do here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really believe that particular evaluation of $\int\sin$. Try multiplying by a factor of $\sin$ or possibly $\cos$ of $h/2$

Comment: @FShrike, could you please explain a bit further?

Comment: $\sinh(x)$ is just a linear combination of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$. How would you use Riemann sums to integrate either of these?